# PHP/MySQL - need help getting the list of applicable events for users

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help - there are two tables I've got:

- events (eventID, event_name, event_description) - used to store
  infromation about different events
- events_applied (eventID, userID, date_applied) - used to track what user applied to what event

When a user logs in into the app, he should see only the events that are available to him to apply, or to be more precise, that would be the events he did not apply to yet. Applied events should be hidden. Everything should be printed out in a table with a link to the application.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows; 
    $stmt->bind_result($eventID, $event_name, $event_description);

    echo '<table> 
            <thead> 
            <tr> 
            <th>Event #</th> 
            <th>Event name</th> 
            <th>Event description</th> 
            <th>Apply</th> 
            </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody>'; 
    while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
        echo '<tr> 
        <td>'.$eventID.'</td> 
        <td>'.$event_name.'</td> 
        <td>'.$event_description).'</td> 
        <td><a href="event_apply.php?eventID='.$eventID.'&userID='.$userID.'">Apply</a></td>
        </tr>'; 
    } 
}
```

The issue is that this will print out all of the events, but I need to either remove the "already applied to" events for each user, or (better) - print out the applied event and instead of printing an "apply link", I would print out "sorry, you already applied to this event.

How can I do that? I was thinking, maybe within the while loop I could do this `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT eventID FROM events_applied WHERE userID = ?";` but it seems kinda messy :/

**EDIT/NEW INFO**
I have expanded the "events" table with "max_people" parameter - so I can limit the number of people signing up for each event.

How would I modify the code in order NOT to show events that are already full?

This is the answer that works currently:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN events_applied ea
    ON ea.eventID = eID.eventID AND ea.userID = :userID
WHERE ea.eventID IS NULL
```

I tried to add another WHERE like this:
AND (SELECT COUNT (userID) FROM events_applied WHERE eventID = :eventID

The problem is that I don't know how to get the eventID as a variable - I am printing out all of the events with the while loop, but I need this variable before that, right?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN events_applied ea
    ON ea.eventID = euserID.eventID AND ea.userID = :userID
WHERE ea.eventID IS NULL
```

Where `:userID` is the id of the currently connected user.

This query selects all events and does a `LEFT JOIN` to connect to the events that the current user applied for. Then, the `WHERE` clause eliminates the matched events. As a result, you do get all events for which the current user did not yet applied.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, although, there is not column euserid.eventID, it's just e.eventID :) Would you mind explaining why is LEFT JOIN an antipattern and what would be the case for me to know that I should use left join, and when to use right join?